# angular 2 createElement + click timing issue

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I'm downloading a PDF Blob from a REST endpoint, then attempting to open it in my angular 2 app.  There seems to be a timing issue where this code sometimes works flawlessly, sometimes it has no result.  If I add a 1 second sleep after the link creation & click it works consistently.  I'm thinking there's some angular 2 DOM manipulation issue?  I'm an angular rookie, so my only guess was to run it in the NgZone (which didn't help).

```
//Get the PDF data
let data = await getFileBlob();
let fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

//Manipulate the DOM to view it
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = fileUrl;
a.target = "_blank";
a.download = new Date().toISOString() + fileExtension;
let addedAnchor = document.body.appendChild(a);
addedAnchor.click();
document.body.removeChild(addedAnchor);
```

Comment: Is getFileBlob() returning promise? If so why are you passing that into createObjectURL()?

Comment: Another way to achieve what you're doing, is to have all template already declared, but hidden using an `*ngIf` directive. This way, you could inject your pdf into the template controlled with `ngIf` without worrying about the time that the DOM manipulation takes.

Comment: @Sharko - Sorry I took bits and pieces of my current larger app to put the code sample together.  I changed the promise.then to an `await`, which is more accurate.

Comment: @MaximeFlament - good thought.  I have this logic in a few visual places, so I was hoping to avoid doing `*ngIf` additions in numerous places.  Would Angular's `Renderer2` be an option?

Comment: I found a great tutorial about creating template dynamically with re-usable code (similar to a  Factory pattern) here: https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36
Maybe you could take a look at it if the template you need to create is duplicated in some other components :)